# How to make minibatch data out of pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like the following.
I wrote example just for two assets(A00033, A00034) and just for one day 2012-01-01.

| date | etf | data_nmae | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-01 | A00033 | open | 3 |
| 2012-01-01 | A00033 | high | 4 |
| 2012-01-01 | A00033 | close | 2 |
| 2012-01-01 | A00033 | volume | 1 |
| 2012-01-01 | A00033 | low | 1 |
| 2012-01-01 | A00034 | open | 31 |
| 2012-01-01 | A00034 | high | 43 |
| 2012-01-01 | A00034 | close | 32 |
| 2012-01-01 | A00034 | volume | 3 |
| 2012-01-01 | A00034 | low | 11 |

In this case, I want to generate numpy dataset having shape (n_channel, lookback, n_assets) where lookback is training period and n_assets is number of all assets I have and n_channel is 5 (open, high, close, low, volume).

How can I manipulate numpy and pandas make this minibatch data??

Comment: what are batch, n_channel, and n_assets?

Comment: better yet: please provide (a sample) of expected output with requirements description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the answer you are looking for :

```py
>>> df.groupby('date')[['etf', 'data_nmae']].nunique().reset_index().rename(columns={'date': 'lookback', 'etf': 'n_assets', 'data_nmae': 'n_channel'})

    lookback    n_assets    n_channel
0   2012-01-01  2           5
```